# JSF 2.0 h:datatable not using supplied id attribute

Tags: jsf-2

I'm observing the following behavior within a JSF 2 page (Mojarra 2.1.18 / RedHat EAP 6.1, if that's useful).  I've got a form wrapping a data table, and I'm supplying an ID attribute value for both the form and the table.  When I view the resulting html source file, I see that the table ID is set to an auto-generated value and the form ID attribute is not prepended to the auto-generated table ID.  That is:

This set of tags:

```
<h:form id="form4">
   <h:datatable id="notices" ...>
    ...
   </h:datatable>
</h:form>
```

Yields the following html:

```
<form id="form4" ...>
   <table id="j_itd68"> //i.e. id != "notices"
   ...
   </table>
</form>
```

There are more elements in the JSF xhtml file preceding the h:form/h:datatable, but I've intentionally excluded them here (hoping that someone might recognize this symptom without additional clutter).  Things go wrong for me when I attempt to include some PrimeFaces p:commandbutton instances within the table.  They don't get named properly (i.e. they don't include the enclosing form ID in the generated ID), and this causes a "component not found for ID" servlet error.  The same improper naming occurs if I replace the p:commandbutton instances with h:commandbutton instances (so I don't believe this is a PrimeFaces issue).   This behavior seems like the result of a malformed JSF page, but I haven't found anything yet (a NetBeans XML check on the JSF xhtml file returns a successful result).  Any help is appreciated.

Best regards,

-Andy

Comment: OK, so I figured it out.  I left out an important detail - I was binding a datatable component to the id="notices" h:datatable i.e. `<h:datatable id="notices" binding="#{bean.datatable}"`, where the bean was in session scope and already backed a different page in the application (with a binding to a separate h:datatable on that page).  My attempt to bind another h:datatable tag to the same bean's datatable component resulted in the strange ID behavior I reported.  I've since put the "overloaded" backing bean in view scope and this has resolved the problem.  Hope this can help someone out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reference components in JSF ajax? Cannot find component with identifier "foo" in view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-reference-components-in-jsf-ajax-cannot-find-component-with-identifier)

Comment: @perissf - I don't agree that this is a duplicate question.  I had reviewed the thread you cited before posting my question and it didn't seem related to my specific error.  My error was caused by improper overloading of a bound component on a backing bean in the session scope and that translated into a rejection of the supplied value for the datatable's id attribute.  This seems like a different problem/solution vs. the possible duplicate question you provide.